# using fork in if conditional

Tags: c, unix, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void fork4 () 
{
    printf("\n [%d] L0 \n", getpid());
    if ( fork() != 0 )
    {
        printf("\n [%d] L1  \n" , getpid());
        if ( fork() != 0)
        {
            printf("\n [%d] L2 \n" , getpid());
            fork();
        }
    }
    printf("\n [%d] Bye \n" , getpid());
}

int main()
{
    fork4();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 [4141] L0 

 [4141] L1  

 [4142] Bye 

 [4141] L2 

 [4141] Bye 

 [4143] Bye 

 [4144] Bye
```

I'm trying to understand what exactly is happening but the output is very strange! I don't understand why the parent process can enter the first if scope! Would it be alright if someone explained what is happening here?

Comment: The result of `fork()` is non-zero in the parent process (positive for success, -1 for failure) and zero in the child process. This is so because the parent needs to get the process id of the child; the child process can always get the process id of its current parent (natural or adoptive) by calling `getppid()`.  *Only* the parent process can enter the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the output.

You can see only process with **ID:4141** is able to get into `if` statements. Because after successful creation of child process, the return value from `fork()` is child process ID.

The process **id:4141** is your parent process. And this process is calling `fork()` statements, which creates the child process **4142,4143,4144...**

None of these processes (**4142,4143**) can go into your `if` statement. Because for these processes the return value is zero from the successful execution of `fork()` statement.

For process **4142** and **4143**, the next statement of execution after they get created from `fork()` is the "Bye" statement.